# My Rust program did not run successfully and returned exit code 3

Tags: postgresql, rust, rust-tokio, actix-web, rust-diesel

##### When I build a web application using the Rust programming language, I use:

- The actix-web and actix-rt frameworks
- Diesel to interact with the database
- Postgres as the database storage

##### Currently, I have only written functionality to connect to the database and retrieve information from tables in the database.

After running the `cargo check` command, my output is as follows:

```bash
Finished dev [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 0.44s
```

However, when I run the `cargo run` command, the program returns an error code without indicating where the problem may
lie:

```bash
Finished release [optimized] target(s) in 0.33s
     Running `D:\Source\web-server\target\release\users.exe`
error: process didn't exit successfully: `D:\Source\web-server\target\release\users.exe` (exit code: 3)
```

#### This is an illustration

[image]

#### I tried changing the Actix macro `#[actix_rt::main]` to `#[tokio::main]` but it did not work.

Before

```rust
#[actix_rt::main]
async fn main() -> std::io::Result<()> {
    let pool: PgPool = create_connection();
    run_migrations(&mut pool.get().expect("Can't run migrate"));
    let schema = Data::new(user_create_schema_with_context(pool));

    HttpServer::new(move || {
        App::new().configure(user_route).app_data(schema.clone())
    }).bind(("0.0.0.0", 80))?.run().await
}
```

sau

```rust
#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> std::io::Result<()> {
let pool: PgPool = create_connection();
    run_migrations(&mut pool.get().expect("Can't run migrate"));
    let schema = Data::new(user_create_schema_with_context(pool));

    HttpServer::new(move || {
        App::new().configure(user_route).app_data(schema.clone())
    }).bind(("0.0.0.0", 80))?.run().await
}
```

#### I also tried changing Actix Frameworks to Rocket framework but it still doesn't work

Comment: Please edit your question to include a [reprex].

Comment: "Doesn't work" isn't a technical diagnostic we can help with. You'll need to disable some of the functionality in here until it works, then carefully restore bit by bit until you see exactly what causes the fault.

Comment: That's very likely due to a broken libpq version: https://github.com/diesel-rs/diesel/discussions/2947

Answer (score 2):

its a bug from a C library that effect on diesel r2d2 and postgres in windows machine

[github issue page](https://github.com/diesel-rs/diesel/discussions/2947)

Answer (score 0):

You may want to double check your Cargo.toml. The mispell of feature when it is expecting features could make a difference.

Another thing is did you include the "mod users;" in main.rs if you are also set_routes via actix-web for users rest api.

Just a few thoughts that came up.